# Issues with Ramanujan's Master Theorem

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

I was looking at [Ramanujan's Master Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RamanujansMasterTheorem.html) and have seem to have run into a problem.

On the page linked, in the example $\phi(k)=1$ so $F(x) = e^{-x}$ and it is shown trivially that

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x} x^{n-1}\,dx=\Gamma(n)$$

However, if I were to let, for example, $\phi(k)=\cos(2\pi k)$ then $F(x)=e^{-x}$ again, but I would conclude (incorrectly) that

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x} x^{n-1}\,dx=\Gamma(n)\cos(2\pi n)$$

What restrictions am I missing here?

Comment: Why do you believe your second statement is incorrect?  (After the correction from $\cos(2\pi k)$ to $\cos(2\pi n)$, which is what I presume you mean).  While the use of $\Gamma()$ is a bit strange, the fact that the theorem uses $n$ for its statement would seem to suggest that it expects $n\in\mathbb{N}$...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thanks for the correction.  All the examples I can see e.g. [here](http://129.81.170.14/~vhm/papers_html/rmt-final.pdf) seem to half for all $n \in \mathbb{R}$ and nothing says that there is a restriction to integers (at least that I can find)

Comment: Argon: I see what you mean; on the other hand, that paper suggests a growth condition (in the statement of Theorem 3.2) that might be relevant here?  In particular, $\cos(2\pi k)\approx e^{2\pi |t|}$ for $k=it$ which would seem to violate the conditions there.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Indeed, perhaps this condition is implied.  However, (3.2) has a different series expansion than (4.1), and (4.1) makes no reference to this condition.  Should the condition be assumed for (4.1) as well, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

The theorem relies on calculating the inverse Mellin transform of $\Gamma(s)\phi(-s)$:
$$ F(x) = \frac1{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}x^{-s}\Gamma(s)\phi(-s)\,ds $$
(see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_inversion_theorem; I don't have the right books at hand just now to give a better reference).

That integral needs to converge, so the reason you can't substitute $\phi(s)=\cos 2\pi s$ is that the integral would then diverge as $\Im s\to\pm\infty$. Wikipedia's page on Mellin inversion theorem says it is sufficient for $\Gamma(s)\phi(-s)$ to tend uniformly to zero as $|\Im s|\to\infty$.